# Firefox prompts an error when I tried to open an HTML file

Tags: firefox, window

When I try to open an HTML file with Firefox, I get an error message similar to the following one:

> Windows cannot find 'E:\blar blar\something\example.htm'. Make sure your typed the name correctly, and then try again.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is `E:` drive a `subst` drive and you are running Firefox in a different context than the command window you used to `subst` the drive? E.g. command window in the admin context and Firefox in the limited user context?

Answer (score 0):

the error says the name is wrong, you might have typed it in incorrectly.

open the folder E:\blar blar\something and double click, or drag the file 'example.htm' into firefox.

Comment: it could be also because your filename is example.html , not example.htm

Comment: i already double click the file  but  it pop-up .

Comment: it wd be good if you could post a sceenshot of the error . seems like you are getting a msg window from javascript or like.